# Api Rest, metodo get, como pasar parametros de tipo array

Tags: javascript, angular, api, rest

Tengo desarrollado una api restfull en Node.js, el cliente esta desarrollado en angular, como puedo enviar parametros de tipo array en un get, se debe enviar por el header o por los parametros?. Actualmente lo envio en el body de un post pero no quiero usar este metodo para obtener informacion.

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal restfull, si la acción es un get los parámetros se tratan como filtros y, debe ir en la URL, si es un post, debe ir en el body.

Comment: hay diferentes formas, según el tamaño y la estructura del array (si es unidimensional o tiene varios niveles) podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: Es un arreglo de string de  _id de colleccion de mongoDB y no se si quepa en la URL.

Comment: siempre podes base64 encodear un json, pero no sería mejor pasar el criterio de selección al api y que genere su propia lista de objectIds ? según el navegador y sistema operativo el tamaño maximo de url es 1024 (windoze 32 bits+iexplore) o 64k los navegadores y sistemas mas nuevos

Answer (score 0):

Depende de qué estés usando para levantar tu API. En el caso de express (y loopback), una ruta del tipo:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

});
```

Puede capturar los parámetros del query string usando `req.query`. Por ejemplo:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.query);
});
```

Si llamas a una URL del tipo

```
http://localhost:3000/?a=1&a=2&a=3
```

La consola loguea:

```
{ a: [ '1', '2', '3' ] }
```

Si estás usando otro framework, lo importante es que tengas acceso a la variable que contiene la URL completa del request, y usar sobre ella el módulo `url` que viene incorporado en node. Digamos:

```
    var address = 'http://localhost:3000/?a=1&a=2&a=3';

    var url = require('url');
    var url_parts = url.parse(address, true);

    console.log(url_parts.query);
```

Y eso imprime lo mismo que el ejemplo de arriba